# AWS boto3 image waiter is not working properly

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, lambda, boto3

I am trying to write a python script with boto3 to create an AMI of an instance and tag the AMI and snapshots. Once the AMI creation function executes I want the script to wait/sleep until the resources are created. To do that I tried the below function. But it doesn't work, Any help here?

```
  ec2res = boto3.resource('ec2')
  ec2res.Image('ami-XXXXXX').wait_until_exists()
```

Comment: We need more detail about what "doesn't work" means. Is the image available, but it's in pending state? If so, the SDK suggests that you can supply a filter on state=available.

Comment: Image state is in pending, I tried using filter even though it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

The image exists.  Otherwise you wouldn't have an image ID to plug into your code.  That's why the waiter is returning immediately.  What you likely want is [Image Available](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html?highlight=ec2#EC2.Waiter.ImageAvailable)